# Proper CSS doesn't match my original design

Tags: html, css

I created a page here: http://www.iliveaccountable.com/mytestsite/the-experience/

Cause I imitate this registration section here: https://thrivecompany.le-vel.com/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fAccount

But now all i got is messed up outlook that doesn't look good on that page.

What should I modify on my page CSS to make it look exactly the page i imitate?

Can you help me and inspect elements to see what needs to be change? I'm really stuck.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="column rightside">
            <div class="content-block">
                <h3><span class="icon16 profile"></span>Create New Customer Account</h3>

<form action="/Login/CreateAccount" id="CreateAccountForm" method="post"><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="aMoBEQMbxqA8VfDiztisqe7tTDwFTiGwrVj7h5XkBWE7HgMGmgevBnzjzxTOb47-X5mgBDl4jXwyseojmOYFDABGXUj91yrEuSbJCsxM9081">    <div class="content-block">
        <div class="FormRow">
            <strong>Please confirm your referring Promoter:</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="FormRow">
            <label class="auto">
                <input checked="checked" data-val="true" data-val-booleanrequired="You Must Confirm Your Retailer" data-val-required="You Must Confirm Your Retailer" id="ConfirmRetailer" name="ConfirmRetailer" type="radio" value="True">
                <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="ConfirmRetailer" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                I was referred by <strong>Nicole Anderson (thrivecompany)</strong>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="FormRow">
            <label class="auto">
                <input id="ConfirmRetailer" name="ConfirmRetailer" type="radio" value="False">
                I was referred by someone else
            </label>
        </div>
        <div id="CreateAccount_ChangeReferralForm" class="center" style="display: none;">
            <div class="FormRow">
                <strong>http://
                <input data-val="true" data-val-regex="Invalid Characters" data-val-regex-pattern="(?!^\d+$)^[a-zA-Z0-9_]{3,15}$" data-val-remote="That Username does not exist" data-val-remote-additionalfields="*.ChangeUsername" data-val-remote-url="/JSON/CheckUsernameExists" id="ChangeUsername" name="ChangeUsername" type="text" value="">
                    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="ChangeUsername" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                    .le-vel.com</strong>
            </div>
            <div class="FormRow">
                <a class="Button ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" id="ChangeReferralButton" href="/Login/ClearReferral" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text">Update My Referrer</span></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="CreateAccount_MainForm">
        <div class="FormRow">
            <label>Country:</label>
            <select id="ShipCountry" name="ShipCountry"><option value="AU">Australia</option>
<option value="CA">Canada</option>
<option value="GB">United Kingdom</option>
<option value="NZ">New Zealand</option>
<option selected="selected" value="US">United States</option>
</select>
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="ShipCountry" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="FormRow">
            <label>First Name:</label>
            <input data-val="true" data-val-required="Please Enter Your First Name" id="FirstName" name="FirstName" type="text" value="">
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="FirstName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="FormRow">
            <label>Last Name:</label>
            <input data-val="true" data-val-required="Please Enter Your Last Name" id="LastName" name="LastName" type="text" value="">
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="LastName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="FormRow">
            <label>Email Address:</label>
            <input data-val="true" data-val-email="Please Enter a Valid Email Address" data-val-remote="Your Email Address Has Been Used Already" data-val-remote-additionalfields="*.Email" data-val-remote-url="/JSON/CheckEmailAvailable" data-val-required="An Email Address is Required" id="Email" name="Email" type="text" value="">
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Email" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="FormRow">
            <label>Choose Username:</label>
            <input data-val="true" data-val-length="Must Be 5 to 15 Characaters" data-val-length-max="15" data-val-length-min="3" data-val-regex="Invalid Characters" data-val-regex-pattern="(?!^\d+$)^[a-zA-Z0-9_]{3,15}$" data-val-remote="Username Already Taken" data-val-remote-additionalfields="*.UserName" data-val-remote-url="/JSON/CheckUsernameAvailable" data-val-required="A Username is Required" id="UserName" name="UserName" type="text" value="">
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="UserName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="FormRow">
            <label>Password:</label>
            <input data-val="true" data-val-length="Minimum 6 Characters" data-val-length-max="25" data-val-length-min="6" data-val-required="A Password is Required" id="Password" name="Password" type="password">
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Password" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="FormRow">
            <label>Confirm Password:</label>
            <input data-val="true" data-val-equalto="Passwords Don't Match" data-val-equalto-other="*.Password" data-val-required="Please Confirm Your Password" id="PasswordConfirm" name="PasswordConfirm" type="password">
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="PasswordConfirm" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="FormRow">
            <label></label>
            <button type="submit" id="CustomerLoginButton" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text">Create Customer Account</span></button>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="returnUrl">
    </div>
</form>

            </div>
    </div>



    </div>

</div>
```

Here's the added CSS:

```
html, body {
    position: relative;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #555;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 1000px;
    min-height: 600px;
    background-color: #FFF;
}


h3 {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0 0 5px 0;
    padding: 0 0 2px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ECECEC;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #222;
     font-size: 15px;
}

.column {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
width: 100%;
}

.content-block {
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    background-color: #FCFCFC;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 20px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px 0 #EEE;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px 0 #EEE;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px 0 #EEE;
}

.content-block {
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

span.icon16.profile {
    background-position: -32px 0;
}

span.icon16 {
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    vertical-align: text-bottom;
    margin-right: 4px;
    float: left;
    background: url('https://media.le-vel.com/Images/ColorIcons_16.png') no-repeat;
    text-indent: -9999px;
}
```

PLEASE HELP!

Comment: PLEASE HELP! Anybody?

Comment: You'll have a hard time finding someone willing to go through your entire site trying to find issues. Try and narrow your problem to one specific issue and provide the minimum code necessary to reproduce that issue.

Comment: Hi Steve. Yeah that page is the only page I need to check.

Comment: You're still providing the entire page and only saying "It's messed up". That's not much to go on and is too broad a question to fit here. Take a look at how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: Just edited and narrow down the codes.

Comment: Alright -4 and No help. Thanks so much guys.

Comment: You still have a lot of code, you're not providing any specific question, and you're linking to offsite locations which people tend not to visit. You need to ask a *specific* question, provide a snippet or JSFiddle reproducing the issue, and possibly screenshots illustrating what you are having issues with. Also, begging for help generally doesn't behoove people to assist.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're dealing with more than one style sheet (which is not uncommon). On your site that you linked to, I right-clicked in Chrome and inspected one of your text fields (you should do this whenever something doesn't look the way you want).

If you haven't discovered them already, Firefox and Chrome's developer tools are real lifesavers. I like Firefox's javascript debugging and Chrome's css tools. I particularly like Chrome for css because you can play around with any kind of css variations and see all the possibilities for a particular element and then see what they do in real time.

What is probably going on is that whatever site stylesheet you have (it looks like it's called style.css on your site) is controlling the behavior. You can, of course, override the site stylesheet by specifying specific stylings by class/id.

Tip: Greater specificity gets greater priority in css. If styling on a particular tag (like `h3`) is being overridden, try clarifying classes and Ids and then target those (e.g. `.rightside h3`. If all else fails, add `!important` to the end of the css line and that will take priority over just about anything else except inline styling (which you should avoid in almost every situation).

I bang my head up against CSS all day long at my job. I have to work within a Joomla site and there are half a dozen stylesheets that I have no control over. I've learned it's important to look at what else might be affecting the styling of a particular element, then I can know why my css isn't giving me what I want.